# How can I order categories by a left joined links views?

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, sum

I would like to have a list with categories that are ordered by the total links views from another table.

I just try to google a little and came up with this example.

```
    SELECT 
    'categories'.'catId',
    'categories'.'title',
    'categories'.'description',
    (
        SELECT SUM(hits)
        FROM 'links'
        WHERE 'catId' = 'categories'.'catId'
    ) AS 'hits_count'
FROM 'categories'
LEFT JOIN 'links'
ON 'links'.'catId' = 'categories'.'catId'
WHERE 'status'='1'
ORDER BY 'hits_count'
```

Would this work? Or is there another way to do it?

the latest attemp

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$db = new DB();
$sql="SELECT categories.name,
    (
        SELECT SUM(hits)
        FROM links
        WHERE catId = categories.catId
    ) AS hits_count
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN links
ON links.catId = categories.catId
WHERE links.status=1
ORDER BY hits_count DESC";

$query = $db->db->prepare($sql);
$categories = $query->execute();
?>
<?php print_r($categories) ?>
```

did only return with the number 1

Comment: why are you using single quotes?

Comment: Have you run this code? If you have, then you know, if it works or not. If you haven't, then go and run it to see, if it works.

Comment: without single quotes its fine it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would phrase this as a join between `categories` and a subquery which finds the sums:

```
SELECT
    c.catId,
    c.title,
    c.description,
    COALESCE(l.hits_count, 0) AS hits_count
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT catId, SUM(hits) hits_count
    FROM links
    GROUP BY catId
) l
    ON l.catId = c.catId
WHERE
    c.status = 1
ORDER BY
    hits_count;
```

By using a join instead of a correlated subquery you should get a boost in performance.  But perhaps the bigger problem you have is that you are putting single quotes around everything.  Don't do that, because MySQL might interpret that as a string literal.  If you need to escape a table or column name in MySQL, use backticks.  But in your case, I don't think you need them at all.

Comment: also just returns 1

Comment: @nicolaiolsen Then the problem lies with your PHP code.  My query should address all the problems on the SQL side.

Comment: i updated your answer with my latest code. can you see the problem ther?

Comment: sorry i had forgot to fetchAll

Comment: @nicolaiolsen My PHP is relatively weak.  I feel your code is where the problem is and not the query.

Comment: i forgot the FetchAll and i fix it and now its working perfect. thx for the help